# Obtain missing datetime - dataseries- from dataset Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I've searched on the internet, and I've found a similar question where I've got the part of the code, but I cannot add a comment to the person who posted the code due to my reputation.
I have a test dataset that is composed of DateTime - Value; those values are obtained by sensors each minute, but the sensor is not perfect, so I have two files during the same period but with different length and patterns because sometimes it takes the measure twice in the same minute.

[Current test dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwrYU.png) doesn't have data for the 10th minute, so the program below should show me that that row is missing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# testing data
data = pd.read_excel("testing.xlsx")

# Set Attribute Date to Pandas Datetime
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
# Round Time into minutes
data['Date'] = pd.Series(data['Date']).dt.round("1min")
# Remove duplicates keeping one
data.drop_duplicates(subset ="Date", keep = "first", inplace = True)
# Change date order, because date_range increment month and not day
date['Date'] = data['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
# Data Range between initial date and final date 
date_range = pd.date_range(date['Date'][date.index[0]], date['Date'][date.index[-1]], freq='1Min')

# Transform the column (it's a string) to datetime type
dt = pd.to_datetime(date['Date'])

# create datetime index passing the datetime series
dato = pd.DatetimeIndex(dt.values)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 20, (dato.shape[0], 1)))
df.index = dato  # set index

df_missing = df.drop(df.between_time('02:12', '02:14').index)

#check for missing datetimeindex values based on reference index (with all values)
missing_dates = df.index[~df.index.isin(date.index)]

print(missing_dates)
```

And the current output is:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-01 02:00:00', '2019-04-01 02:01:00',
               '2019-04-01 02:02:00', '2019-04-01 02:03:00',
               '2019-04-01 02:04:00', '2019-04-01 02:05:00',
               '2019-04-01 02:06:00', '2019-04-01 02:07:00',
               '2019-04-01 02:08:00', '2019-04-01 02:09:00',
               '2019-04-01 02:11:00', '2019-04-01 02:12:00',
               '2019-04-01 02:13:00', '2019-04-01 02:14:00',
               '2019-04-01 02:15:00', '2019-04-01 02:16:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

When it should display something like:

```
 DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-01 02:10:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need to perform all the re-indexing etc. - maybe you could clarify on that. The comparison the a specified date_range works perfectly fine as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': ['2019-04-01 02:00:00', '2019-04-01 02:01:00',
                         '2019-04-01 02:02:00', '2019-04-01 02:03:00',
                         '2019-04-01 02:04:00', '2019-04-01 02:05:00',
                         '2019-04-01 02:06:00', '2019-04-01 02:07:00',
                         '2019-04-01 02:08:00', '2019-04-01 02:09:00',
                         '2019-04-01 02:11:00', '2019-04-01 02:12:00',
                         '2019-04-01 02:13:00', '2019-04-01 02:14:00',
                         '2019-04-01 02:15:00', '2019-04-01 02:16:00'],
                   'y': np.arange(16)})
df['t'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'])

# set the time column as index
df = df.set_index(['t'])

# target: date_range 1 min steps
tgt = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='min')

# now use .isin() and negate to get the timestamps that are missing in df
print(tgt[~tgt.isin(df.index)])
# DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-01 02:10:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='T')
```

Comment: Thanks, MrFuppes, your code was the solution, specifically the part of date_range and .isin()